# How to link STL in c++ code?

Tags: c++, stl

I wrote some code in source file `sql_parse.cc` of `MySql 5.5.7rc`. There I have used `vector`, `allocator`, etc but the compiler is not being linked with Standard Template Library(STL). Can anybody suggest me what should I do?

Here is the error msg :

```
libsql.a(sql_parse.cc.o): In function `std::vector<std::basic_string<char,  
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::push_back(std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
sql_parse.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorISsSaISsEE9push_backERKSs[std::vector<std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::push_back(std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)]+0x74): undefined reference to 
`std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, 
std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > 
>::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Make sure you use `g++` to link.

Comment: "Its urgent" wouldn't help at all.

Comment: That's true, "it's urgent" should be more precise. For example: "if you see this question and it's more than an hour old, don't bother answering because it'll be too late by then".

Answer (score 21):

You should've given the command line. I suspect that you use `gcc` for linking in which case you should either use `g++` or add `-lstdc++` option.

Comment: No i tried g++ also but didn't work.Was getting the same error. Like what i did is "sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-plugin-partition --with-tcp-port=3308 --with-unix-socket-path=/tmp/mysql1.sock --with-debug CXX=g++"

Comment: no, that's not what I mean, I meant using `g++` for linking. Tracking down what's wrong with configure and build process may get tricky. You can try to add `LIBS=-lstdc++` to configure line, but I'd be concerned about the whole thing even if it works...

Comment: Hey how to use -lsdc++ ??

And where to add this?

Comment: Just like you did with CXX. What gcc version do you have on that machine?

Comment: It looks like mysql build process is broken, actually, I'm afraid I can't afford sorting this out in the nearest five hours and then you said it's urgent. You may just try to hand edit the Makefile in question, try `LD=g++` or some tricks like that...

Comment: Hey how to use g++ for linking only, as u said??

Comment: U try please...i meant i need it as soon as possible...I m trying ur second option..

Comment: In makefile we have like this....


INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM = @INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM@

KILL = @KILL@

LD = @LD@

LDFLAGS = @LDFLAGS@

As u can see LD=@LD@ so where should i write LD=g++?

Comment: Replace the current `LD=@LD@` line. That apparently is the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

I got my stl code to compile with the following

```
g++ -std=c++11 file.cpp -o prog
```

Answer (score 0):

> `undefined reference to 
>   std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, 
>   std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > 
>   ::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, 
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, 
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, 
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::basic_string<char, 
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'`

That symbol is a member function of `std::vector<std::string>` and is a function template, so should be instantiated in your program, not in the C++ standard library.

Are you compiling with the `-fno-implicit-templates` option? Or using an explicit instantiation declaration (i.e. `extern` template) in your code and not providing the definition?  Those would prevent the compiler from instantiation the template.

If you're telling the compiler not to provide implicit instantiations then you will need to add an explicit instantiation for each undefined reference:

```
template void std::vector<std::string>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<std::string>::iterator, std::string const&);
```

Answer (score -6):

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

#endif  //GLOBAL_H
```

Is a good start

Comment: `using namespace std` should never appear in a header. And, this doesn't relate to a question about linking.